# Getting around the lack of a Left Trim(string, char[]) function in JET / Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado.net, jet

I need to remove leading zeros from a string field in an Access database that is destroyed and recreated every time it is used within a C# program. Most string libraries (even SQL ones) include a Trim function to remove leading or following whitespace. Unfortunately, Access does not seem to have a LTrim(string s, char[] trimChars) or something similar. To get around this, I concocted this monstrosity:

```
Replace(LTrim(Replace(ADDRNO,'0',  ' ')),' ',  '0')
```

But this resulted in an undefined function reference for Replace, even though it is obviously an Access function.

What I am looking for is a way to trim these zeros, either by getting the JET engine to let me use the Replace function or by some other method entirely.

EDIT: Fixed syntax of Replace function. Problem still persists.

Comment: You cannot use replace with ADO : http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/209056-using-replace-function-ado-access-db-visual-basic-6-a

Comment: Is ADDRNO a number? If so, how about Val()

Comment: ADDRNO is a string representation of the address number. Sample values would be '00012' or '00814' or '10346'. I need the '12', '814' and '10346' parts respectively.

Comment: Access has LTrim(), but it won't work when used via data access methods that don't use the Access/Jet expression services. That is, it's just like Replace() -- it can't be used via ADO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

```
Val(ADDRNO)
```

It will return the number portion without the leading zeros.

Comment: Certainly this is the simplest solution if the data is nothing but numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: This did it for me. I guess I was lucky they used a zero for padding; I pity the person who has to deal with nonwhitespace, nonzero padding. Aside from a few data issues ('00N/A'), everything works well. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what context you are running this but this seems to show the parameter order is different and uses double quotes instead of single quotes(I haven't used Access in awhile so maybe it doesn't matter), also try square brackets on column name:

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php

```
Replace(LTrim(Replace([ADDRNO], "0",  " "))," ", "0")
```

If that gives the same error just try the replace function by itself to narrow down the problem:

```
Replace ("alphabet", "a", "e")
```

If this works then you know the Replace function works, and there is some other issue.

Edit: If it doesn't work at all, then Replace is likely a VBA function available only in the Access application, and is not part of Jet.  You could try some combination of Left/Right function and chop the string up, this can get quite ugly.  I personally would just iterate over the record set and use C# code to modify the values.  Hopefully you don't have such a large number of records that this would be a problem.

Comment: I do not believe you can use replace with ADO http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/209056-using-replace-function-ado-access-db-visual-basic-6-a

Comment: Remou is correct. Even just using replace does not work; I still get the undefined function error.

Comment: Didn't know if you were running the query form C# as well.  In that case I'd just do it in C# instead of a query.  It probably won't perform much worse than Jet would.

Comment: Why would you assume stepping through a recordset in C# would be slower than a Jet UPDATE command? I think you're nuts to suggest that Jet would perform as slowly, and would like to hear some justification for the suggestion (other than simple garden-variety Jet/Access bigotry).

Comment: @David A loop in C# would typically be slower because it would be no faster than an O(n) operation, whereas database engines have various ways of implementing set based operations in better than linear time.  So typically the database engine is faster.  How a query scales is not very significant if you are working with small result sets.  If you have to embed complex string manipulations into the query, you can start to see the query's performance degrade significantly.  So there is a balancing act of whether to have a very complex set based operation, vs a less complex iterative operation.

Comment: So, you agree with me that doing it in C# is likely to be slower than letting Jet do it. Right? Obviously, what matters is what functions are available to you via the interface you are using to interact with your database. I am an Access developer so I never interact with Jet/ACE except from Access so I don't have at my fingertips a list of which functions Jet/ACE supports via ODBC/OLEDB. If Val() is supported, then that's clearly the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the order of your parameters that is wrong:

```
debug.? Replace("My string", "i", "o")   -> "My Strong"
```

Comment: Seems like AaronLS was faster than me  :-/

Comment: Now, that is weird. You are correct in that the parameters are wrong, but it seems the Replace function works from within Access. However, I am still getting an error that says Replace is an undefined function when using ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trim and Replace.